# why tf.flags conflicts with argparse?

Tags: tensorflow, argparse

Using `tf.app.flags` and `argparse`, I wrote the code

```py
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

flags.DEFINE_integer('hidden1', 16, 'Number of units in hidden layer 1.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('hidden2', 16, 'Number of units in hidden layer 2.')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Single Deep GCNN 11, 22 and 33!', allow_abbrev=False)
parser.add_argument('--fc-neuron', type=int, default=64)
parser.add_argument('--num-epochs', type=int, default=10000, help='the number of training epochs')
```

And in other files, I used `FLAGS` to get some arguments, however, I got the error

```
absl.flags._exceptions.UnrecognizedFlagError: Unknown command line flag 'fc-neuron'
```

How can I fix this confict?

Comment: Different functions can read the commandline (`sys.argv`o), each with its own expectations of what it can or cannot contain.

Answer (score 1):

So, `absl.flags` is not quite cooperative when working with `argparse` (at least for the versions that I'm still bound to use in 2021).

The workaround that found is to let FLAGS fail on the unknown args gracefully and then argparse your arguments:

```
import argparse
from absl import flags

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--imput_path', type=str)
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output_path', type=str)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
    try:
        argv = FLAGS(sys.argv, known_only=True)  # parse flags
    except flags.Error, e:
        logger.error('%s\nUsage: %s ARGS\n%s' % (e, sys.argv[0], FLAGS))
        sys.exit(1)

    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()
```